# convert range to number where last cell in range is last cell in column with a value

Tags: range, converters

I am attempting to convert a specific column from text to numbers and stop at the last cell that contains a value and not having much luck.  currently it only converts the last cell in column that contains a value. range needs to be H2 to last cell that contains a value in column H:

```
Range("H2").End(xlDown).Select
For Each XCELL In Selection
XCELL.Value = CDec(XCELL.Value)
Next XCELL
```